# Unable to fill mongodb document with external api data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fill my mongodb document with data from unsplash and randomuser api.

```
  const userdata = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=51");
  const imagedat = await axios.get(
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?count=51&client_id=GWDzPpjHk743C2QnVBRxu8PtmOI3npF5sePZZ7o0pg4"
  );
```

I call both apis for 51 results but after 22 results the code under catch gets displayed and only 22 documents get created
[image: mongodb compass]
how to store all 51 results

```
const seeddata = async () => {
  const userdata = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=51");
  const imagedat = await axios.get(
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?count=51&client_id=GWDzPpjHk743C2QnVBRxu8PtmOI3npF5sePZZ7o0pg4"
  );
  try {
    await MemoModel.deleteMany({});
    const userarr = await userdata.data;
    const imagedata = await imagedat.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      const data = new MemoModel({
        name: {
          firstname: `${userarr.results[i].name.first}`,
          lastname: `${userarr.results[i].name.last}`,
          username: `${userarr.results[i].login.username}`,
        },
        about: {
          user: `${userarr.results[i].gender} aged ${userarr.results[i].dob.age}. Rotting here for ${userarr.results[i].registered.age} `,
        },
        location: {
          country: `${
            countryarr[Math.floor(Math.random() * countryarr.length)]
          }`,
          state: `${userarr.results[i].location.state}`,
          city: `${userarr.results[i].location.city}`,
          address: `${userarr.results[i].location.street.name} ,${userarr.results[i].location.street.number}`,
          zipcode: `${userarr.results[i].location.postcode}`,
        },
        email: {
          user: `${userarr.results[i].email}`,
        },
        image: {
          dp: `${userarr.results[i].picture.large}`,
          coverimage: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/?mountains",
        },
        posts: {
          postno: i,
          posttitle: `${imagedata[i].description}`,
          postcontent: `${imagedata[i].urls.regular}`,
          postlikesno: imagedata[i].likes,
          postcommentno: imagedata[i].width,
        },
      });
      await data.save();
    }
  } catch {
    console.log("catastrophic Failure");
  }
};
seeddata().then(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

[image: error being displayed]

Comment: Your document validation is failing because not all worldwide postal codes are numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `(err)` after your `catch` and console it instead of "catastrophic error"? It will give us the whole error that break your code:

```
catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```